# Can I convert a pointer address (i.e. an hex integer) to decimal and octal base int in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *a = nullptr;
    int b;
    a = &b;

    cout << noshowbase;
    cin >> b;
    cout << dec << a << '\t' << oct << a << '\t' << hex << a;
}
```

Consider this code.. It is designed to convert a variable's (here `b`) address (`&b` or `a`) which is a hex integer to `dec` and `oct` values using `<iostream>` stream manipulators.. But on running, the output is same for all of them(`hex`,`dec`,`oct`).. Neither, there is any compilation error. So can you please elaborate the reason for this?? Also the `noshowbase` does not seems to be having any effect on output.. 0x is output anyways before the address..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your topic, there is no such thing as a "hex integer". There are integers and they can be formatted as hex, but the formatting is not an intrinsic part of the integer.

Now, why are pointers always formatted as hex? The reason is that that's the way it is defined to work. I'd also call this convenient, but that might be because I'm familiar with the format and can read some information from it even better than from decimal output. The reason this doesn't change with formatters is that a pointer is not considered an integer. You will also find that pointer arithmetic doesn't behave like integer arithmetic, which is a case where the core language behaves like IOstreams.

So, how to get the format of your choice? Simple, convert the pointer to an integer first, then you can use the formatting of your choice. In order to do that, I would use `size_t i = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&b);`. Depending on the compiler, I would also consider using `uintptr_t` instead of `size_t`, because that one is explicitly intended to hold information from a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

An address is not a hex integer. It's an address.

It just so happens that an address is implemented as an integer, referring to a memory location, and can be reinterpreted as an integer. This is rarely a useful thing to do (particularly if you are a fan of bug-free code), but it comes up now and again. You can use `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a)` to do that. (Note that converting to `int` will *not*, in general, work properly. Remember what I said about bug-free code.) When you print the resultant integer, it will print as a decimal, octal, or hexadecimal integer, depending on the currently-set base.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the pointer to unsigned long first:

```
unsigned long p = (unsigned long) a;
cout << "dec=" << dec << p << endl;
cout << "oct=" << oct << p << endl;
cout << "hex=" << hex << p << endl;
```

Comment: Okay ... I thought declaring int a automatically means that pointer will be an integer variable... Thanks for your help!

Comment: `int` isn't guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer. (And it isn't on common 64bit platforms these days.)

Comment: Some C++ implementations might have pointers larger than `unsigned long`. You need to use `uintptr_t`

Comment: No, `unsigned long` is not okay. On some platforms you need an `unsigned long long` to hold an address. Or, use `uintptr_t`, which is the correct type. However, don't use C-style casts or suggest them where they aren't necessary.