# Cast address of function to UINTPTR_T giving me incorrect result

Tags: c++

I want the value of &add1 in a variable. I tried the suggestions from [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30011332/2207924) but it's not giving the result I expect.

```
uintptr_t add1Address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&add1);
```

At this point, add1Address is equal to `11669784`, which is `0x00B21118`

However my debugger, (and inspecting memory with HxD) tells me that &add1 = `0x00B217C0`

What is happening here?

Full code as follows

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int add1(int num, int num2);

int add1(int num, int num2)
{
        return num + num2;
}

int main(void)
{

    uintptr_t add1Address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&add1);
    std::cout << std::hex << add1Address;

}
```

What I'm seeing in [debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZRZc.jpg) is here

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @geza visual studio, removed the printf; to make it clearer the problem isn't printing.

Comment: "However my debugger, (and inspecting memory with HxD) tells me..." - how exactly does it tell you that? Most likely you are jumping to some unfounded assumptions. The correct value is indeed `0x00B21118`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a wild guess.

It is because maybe you have incremental linking on.

Check out this: [c++ function addresses coming out different in attached profiler library than in the subject code base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003759/c-function-addresses-coming-out-different-in-attached-profiler-library-than-in/)

Comment: I don't believe so: `No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)`  however the area of memory it refers to does contain a jump instruction.  In fact any function seems to return the address of a similar instruction:

Comment: @JeffUK: Well, that "jump instruction" is the actual true begining of your function, so the above code gives you a perefectly correct result. What is the problem then?

Comment: The answer, then, is that visual studio does not show the 'true beginning of my function'

Comment: @JeffUK: A function code might have 12345 different entry points, each one as good as any other. A compiled function in object file is not a compact region of code with well defined "beginning" and "end". Object code has entry points and noting else. Other than that, it is an eclectic blob of code. The compiler gave you the *proper* entry point for your function. If you consider something else as the "true beginning" of your function - that's OK, but I'm afraid the compiler is unaware of your preferences.

Comment: @JeffUK: can you please share the .exe and .pdb? I'm really curious what's inside, if incremental linking is off, but you still get jmp table.

Comment: .. Just went to grab them and there is an "Incremental Linker File" hiding there, does that mean it's turned on?...  let me re-check the settings but it definitely said it was off.

Comment: Created a new project, turned off incremental linking and now it's working as I expect. I've marked as duplicate and closed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

At the address you are getting is a jump to the address the debugger is showing. This allows the function to be redirected.

For example:

```
add1:
00B211EF  jmp         add1 (0B21730h)
```

The value of `add1Address` will be `0x00B211EF`, but Visual Studio will show `0x00B21730` as the address of `add()`.